# Force Samba to only listen on loopback

Tags: samba

If I set `interfaces = lo`, then Samba won't start:

```
daemon_status: daemon 'nmbd' : No local IPv4 non-loopback interfaces available, waiting for interface ...
```

I *need* it to start on loopback, because I need to access samba shares via the loopback interface specifically. How would I do that, if it's technically possible at all?

Comment: Why do you need to access Samba via 'loopback' ? The whole idea behind Samba is to allow file sharing between computers.

Comment: @RowlandPenny Windows and WSL share localhost and accessing WSL's proper network doesn't work with Cisco AnyConnect.